# Scrapy KeyError: 'Item does not support field: url'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning to make spiders and have been trying to figure out this little bug. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

When I run my spider I receive an error like so stating:

> KeyError: 'SoapguildItem does not support field: url'

Below is the code I have been working on:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from soapguild.items import SoapguildItem

class SoapySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'soapy'
allowed_domains = ['soapguild.org']
start_urls = ['http://www.soapguild.org/']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    href = SoapguildItem()
    href['url'] = response.url
    # Email
    email = response.xpath("//div/div[1]/p[2]/a[1]/@href").extract()
    email = email.replace("mailto:", "")
    #email = email.replace("(at)". "@")
    location = response.xpath("//div/div[1]/p[1]/text()[2]").extract()
    #location
    location = response.xpath("//div/div[1]/p[1]/text()[2]").extract()
    #contact
    contact = response.xpath("//div/div[1]/p[2]/text()[1]").extract() 
    contact = contact.replace("Contact: ", "")
    #website 
    website = response.xpath("//div/div[1]/p[2]/a[2]//@href").extract()

    for item in zip(email,location,contact,website):
        scraped_info = {
            'Email' : item[0],
            'Location' : item[1],
            'Contact' : item[2],
            'Website' : item[3]
        }

        yield scraped_info
```

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to add the below code to my items.py

    url = scrapy.Field()

Answer (score 2):

Your Item file "SoapguildItem" does not contain url named member variable, please define url.

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class SoapguildItem(Item):
    url = Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add url as your field in items.py? I think the error comes from here: href[‘url’]

Answer (score 0):

```
people_item = PeoplItem();
people_item.__class__.table_name='people_20216'
```

Comment: An answer without explanations does not help much.